# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform with 32 bit JVM

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm running Glassfish 4.0 on a 64bit Windows 8 platform.  I have both 32bit and 64bit JDK installed on system.  My asenv.conf file points to the 32 bit JDK version but I'm still getting the above error regarding attempting to load a 32 bit dll in a 64 bit environment.  I think that I've validated that I'm truly loading the 32bit version in the server log (see below).

```
    VM invocation command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JRE_32bit\bin\java.exe -cp E:/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -
 XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:NewRatio=2 -Xmx512m -javaagent:E:/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar -client
  -Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1 
  -Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false 
  -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver 
  -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=E:\glassfish4\glassfish/modules/autostart/ 
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=E:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks 
  -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666 -Djava.security.policy=E:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy 
  -Djava.awt.headless=true 
  -Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2 
  -Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000 
  -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=E:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1 
  -Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1 
  -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory 
  -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\glassfish4\glassfish/modules/endorsed;E:\glassfish4\glassfish/lib/endorsed 
  -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=E:\glassfish4\glassfish 
  -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true 
  -Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JRE_32bit/lib/ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JRE_32bit/jre/lib/ext;E:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext 
  -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=E:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks 
  -Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall 
  -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as 
  -Djava.security.auth.login.config=E:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf 
  -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true 
  -Dgosh.args=--nointeractive 
  -Djava.library.path=E:/glassfish4/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;
  C:/Windows;E:/OraClient11g_32/client_3/bin;E:/OraClient11g/client_3/bin;C:/Program Files/Veritas/Veritas Volume Manager;
  C:/Program Files/Veritas/VERITAS Object Bus/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Resource Kits/Tools;C:/Program Files/HP/NCU;
  C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;
  C:/Program Files/Microsoft Network Monitor 3;C:/Program Files/System Center Operations Manager 2007;C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/bin;
  C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.3;C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.4;C:/PHP/v5.5.1;C:/Windows/idmu/common;
  C:/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25;E:/curl;
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Windows Performance Toolkit;E:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config 
  com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain -domainname domain1 -asadmin-args --host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,
  --secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=false,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=true,,,
  --debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,E:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains,,,domain1 -instancename server -verbose false -debug false 
  -asadmin-classpath E:/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar -asadmin-classname com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain 
  -upgrade false -type DAS -domaindir E:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1 -read-stdin true
```

However when I look at the above information, there's a `-Djava.library.path=E:/glassfish4/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;` buried in the path that still refers to the 64bit version.   Is this the reason for my 32bit versus 64bit problem?  I'm new to Java and I know how to set this for an application, but how do I set it for the JVM?

Also when I test the Glassfish version from the command line it shows that I'm running the 32bit JVM.

```
Enter admin user name>  ****
Enter admin password for user "****">
Version = GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89), JRE version 1.7.0_25
Command version executed successfully.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I probably should have started here first, but after I restarted the OS, everything worked properly.  I guess Windows still hasn't gotten away from reboots even for something as simple as a JAVA install.